# Можно ли включить в проект exe?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли включить в проект `exe`, чтобы потом запускать его из основного юнита? Я добавлял через `Project -> Add to project`, но `exe` из юнита не запускается.

Comment: А зачем ? Вы можете и так запускать стороннюю программу из своей. Для этого или можно использоваться стандартные ф-ции библиотеки языка, или WinAPI (Crea
teProcess, например). Не говоря уже о всяких компонентах.

Comment: Ну, если Вы хотите несколько проектов в один объединить, то скиньте Ваш exe-шник в папку, в которой лежит проект (например ...\каталог проекта\Bin\....exe), и запускайте его функцией, например, ShellExecute - вернёт число меньше, чем 32 при неудачном запуске, объявлена в модуле ShellAPI.

Comment: вы хотите прикомпилировать к своей программе другой ехе файл? и иметь возможность запускать этот файл из своей программы?
тогда копайте в сторону ресурсов приложения. нужно представить требуемый ехе файл, как ресурс вашего приложения, и после запуска вашей программы(например при событии онкриейт главной формы) извлекать этот ехе файл во временную папку, или в папку с вашим приложением...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShellExecute` Вам в помощь )